# How to Import Integer as Numeric String and not in Scientific Notation

Tags: python, json, pandas

Trying to import a JSON file which is list of dictionaries, one of which contains two epoch time values (start time and end time). Now, if all instances include both times, no problem--pandas json.normalize will load all values correctly as they appear in the source data. But because some end-time values are missing altogether, python needs to have an 'Nan' and so the entire column of the df is apparently string, AND, apparently because of that (I don't know), all values that DO exist are changed to exponential notation, rendering the data useless.

Here's a typical JSON file:

```
[ {
    "id": "U1Q6MDpERVNLVE9Q",
    "A": {
        "ProcessName": "A3463453",
        "SubProcess": "M1",
        "Machine": "46"
    },
    "B": {
        "user": "a12",
        "polhode": "343282"
    },
    "C": {
        "rotorState": "m-mode",
        "startTime": 1671540600000,
        "endTime": 1672963068453,
        "ProcessElapsedMs": 6142877
    },
    "D": "fb6a9154-44a2-3d60-b978-f1d2ad1a68ff"
}, {
    "id": "QVNUOjA6REVTS1RP",
    "A": {
        "ProcessName": "A3465453",
        "SubProcess": "M1",
        "Machine": "47"
    },
    "B": {
        "user": "a12",
        "polhode": "343282"
    },
    "C": {
        "rotorState": "f-mode",
        "startTime": 1671720693000,
        "ProcessElapsedMs": 71973000
    },
    "D": "28e160c9-d954-35d7-a077-70fc70711baf"
}, {
    "id": "NUOjA6REVTS1RPUA",
    "A": {
        "ProcessName": "A3465453",
        "SubProcess": "M3",
        "Machine": "48"
    },
    "B": {
        "user": "a12",
        "polhode": "343282"
    },
    "C": {
        "rotorState": "m-mode",
        "startTime": 1673000200000,
        "endTime": 1673001028516,           
        "ProcessElapsedMs": 10160506
    },
    "D": "ed7077f2-b64c-3944-a0c3-9f0612826c85"
}, {
    "id": "U1Q6MDpERVNLVE9Q",
    "A": {
        "ProcessName": "A3463853",
        "SubProcess": "M3",
        "Machine": "49"
    },
    "B": {
        "user": "a12",
        "polhode": "343282"
    },
    "C": {
        "rotorState": "m-mode",
        "startTime": 1673006529000,
        "endTime": 1673001028516,           
        "ProcessElapsedMs": 3832128
    },
    "D": "0d671793-9679-3e72-9862-f31ad75cfd89"
}, {
    "id": "zMzg5OkRFU0tUT1A",
    "A": {
        "ProcessName": "A3476553",
        "SubProcess": "M18",
        "Machine": "31"
    },
    "B": {
        "user": "a12",
        "polhode": "343282"
    },
    "C": {
        "rotorState": "m-mode",
        "startTime": 1671758829000,
        "endTime": 1672916208140,
        "ProcessElapsedMs": 3832128         
    },
    "D": "1ab25dec-c7d8-3ea8-8dbf-c7c48beaa65a"
}
```

]

and, using this code

```
json_file = open(full_json_path)
json_data = json.loads(json_file.read())
json_df = pd.json_normalize(json_data, max_level=1)
insert_df = json_df[["A.ProcessName", "A.SubProcess", "C.rotorState", "C.startTime", "C.endTime", "C.ProcessElapsedMs"]]
insert_df.columns=["ProcessName", "SubProcess", "GState", "StartEpoch", "EndEpoch", "ProcessElapsedMs"]
print(insert_df.to_string())
```

I get this result:

```
  A.ProcessName A.SubProcess C.rotorState    C.startTime     C.endTime  C.ProcessElapsedMs
```

0      A3463453           M1       m-mode  1671540600000  1.672963e+12             6142877
1      A3465453           M1       f-mode  1671720693000           NaN            71973000
2      A3465453           M3       m-mode  1673000200000  1.673001e+12            10160506
3      A3463853           M3       m-mode  1673006529000  1.673001e+12             3832128
4      A3476553          M18       m-mode  1671758829000  1.672916e+12             3832128

On the other hand, if the data looks like this, no missing EndEpoch values:

```
  ProcessName SubProcess  GState     StartEpoch       EndEpoch  ProcessElapsedMs
```

0    A3463453         M1  m-mode  1671540600000  1672963068453           6142877
1    A3465453         M1  f-mode  1671720693000  1672963068453          71973000
2    A3465453         M3  m-mode  1673000200000  1673001028516          10160506
3    A3463853         M3  m-mode  1673006529000  1673001028516           3832128
4    A3476553        M18  m-mode  1671758829000  1672916208140           3832128

then the result is what I need to have:

```
    ProcessName SubProcess  GState     StartEpoch       EndEpoch  ProcessElapsedMs
```

0    A3463453         M1  m-mode  1671540600000  1672963068453           6142877
1    A3465453         M1  f-mode  1671720693000  1672963068453          71973000
2    A3465453         M3  m-mode  1673000200000  1673001028516          10160506
3    A3463853         M3  m-mode  1673006529000  1673001028516           3832128
4    A3476553        M18  m-mode  1671758829000  1672916208140           3832128

What have I done?

Well, explicitly creating the dataframe with data type of integer doesn't work, because he's going to complain when there's an NaN value that can't be loaded into the integer dataframe column.
Trying to do a replace of the NaN with, say a '0' doesn't work because that has no impact at all on the exp notation values that are already in the data frame.

I'm totally new to Python, and don't care what library function method I use--I just want my data to not be goofed up.  I have to think this is a problem handled routinely, I just don't know what smart questions to ask.

On an unrelated note, I'd also like to be able to use something similar to record_path, if you will, to tell the json.normalize to totally ignore/bypass one or more entire dictionaries--such as "B:" in my example data, so I don't have to import it at all. If you can point me in a direction that would be very helpful.

My apologies for not using correct terminology wherever that may have happened.

Answer (score 1):

`EndEpoch` column contains NaN value which is treated as float, so large float number is displayed as scientific notation by default. You can convert `EndEpoch` column to nullable integers with `df['EndEpoch'] = df['EndEpoch'].astype('Int64')`.

```
# After dtype conversion
print(df)

  ProcessName       SubProcess  GState     StartEpoch       EndEpoch  ProcessElapsedMs
0    A3463453  VXABCSV10P10248  m-mode  1671540600000  1672963068453           6142877
1    A3465453  VXABCSACP202707  f-mode  1671720693000           <NA>          71973000
2    A3465453  VXABHEC10VA0049  m-mode  1673000200000  1673001028516          10160506
3    A3463853  VXABHCOSP101033  m-mode  1673006529000  1673001028516           3832128
4    A3476553  VXABV2CHE600143  m-mode  1671758829000  1672916208140           3832128
```

As far as I know, there is no way for `pd.json_normalize` to ignore some part of json. `record_path` and `meta` argument are designed for extracting inner list of records and extra metadata from json array. Instead you can use [jmespath](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py) to filter the json first.

Comment: ...and you answered despite my goofing up the code block of output data.  This works perfectly--I assumed that the displayed scientific notation, with fewer digits displayed that the source data, meant the information was actually already lost when normalize was run.